# Is it possible to grab a static class dynamically using enum?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to create configuration for my application using static classes.

*Firstly please forgive my ignorance, I'm not a full time c# dev. I come from a Ruby/Javascript world where dynamic access to constants & variables is trivial.*

*Whether or not this is the right approach here I'm not 100% at the moment. Would be greatful of other suggested approaches.*

I have the following static class setup for my config:

```
public static class Config
{
    public static class MaterialQuality
    {
        public static class Low
        {
            public const float Value = 0.1f;
            public const int Cost = 10;
        }

        public static class Medium
        {
            public const float Value = 0.2f;
            public const int Cost = 20;
        }

        public static class High
        {
            public const float Value = 0.2f;
            public const int Cost = 40; 
        }
    }
}
```

I then have a class `Material`, which is passed an enum value relating to the aboves types `Low,Medium,High`.
The reason for the `enum` in unity this gives a quick way for devs to provide level designers with an option list for a an object.

So by choosing an enum value the level designer can set the properties stored in the config without actually having to enter the values directly onto the object. The values are set against the object when it is initialised.

In the constructor I want to set member variables for `Cost` & `Value` from the static config values for the `MaterialQuality` enum value passed.

```
public enum MaterialQuality
{
    Low,Medium,High 
}

public class Material
{
    private int Cost;
    private float Value;

    Material(MaterialQuality quality) {

        Cost = Config.MaterialQuality.<quality>.Cost;
        Value = Config.MaterialQuality.<quality>.Value;

        //in Javascript I'd use associative array access to the object
        Cost = Config.MaterialQuality[quality].Cost;

        //in Ruby we have const_get() on classes.
        Cost = Config.MaterialQuality.const_get(quality).Cost

    }

}
```

The main reason for this approach is to provide single place for configuration & provide a fairly simple way for a non technical person to make changes to parts of the application without having to delve into the main classes. Also it allows me to take advantage of the constants being available in intellisense.

Comment: You should better explain what you want to achieve rather than how to improve your solution, which seems to be a wrong design in terms of how to work with C# and OOP (not only in C#).

Comment: I probably should have mentioned this is part of a unity project.

Comment: Six answers within just one hour - wow...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a fan of using dictionaries for this type of configuration.

```
void Main()
{
    var config = Config.Qualities[MaterialQualities.Low];
    var cost = config.Cost;
    var value = config.Value;
}

public static class Config
{
    public static Dictionary<MaterialQualities, MaterialQuality> Qualities =
        new Dictionary<MaterialQualities, MaterialQuality>
        {
            { MaterialQualities.Low, new MaterialQuality { Value = 0.1F, Cost = 10 }},
            { MaterialQualities.Medium, new MaterialQuality { Value = 0.2F, Cost = 20 }}, 
            { MaterialQualities.High, new MaterialQuality { Value = 0.2F, Cost = 40 }},
        };  
}

public class MaterialQuality
{
    public float Value { get; set; }
    public int Cost { get; set; }
}

public enum MaterialQualities
{
    Low, Medium, High
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I like this alot, it still gives me the use of the enum which in unity3d gives developers a convenient way to present a dropdown selection to a level designer.

Comment: Whilst there are loads of ways it would seem to achieve dynamic access to what I need, this approach best fits the product im building and constraints of providing simple editing for non-technical and separating config from the application logic.

Comment: Glad it worked for you Rob!  I like this approach for these situations since it preserves your enum and keeps it as a core decisionmaker in how your stack responds.  That tends to a repeatable pattern and it makes it easy to make sure that you do not add or create duplicate configurations.

Answer (score 1):

Probably better approach would be:

```
public static class Config
{
    public class Material
    {
        public Material(float value, int cost){
            Value = value;
            Cost = cost;
        }

        public float Value {get; private set;}
        public int Cost {get; private set;}

        public Material GetFor(MaterialQuality quality){
             switch(quality){
                 case MaterialQuality.Low: return new Material(0.1f, 10);
                 case MaterialQuality.Medium: return new Material(0.2f, 20);
                 case MaterialQuality.High: return new Material(0.2f, 40);
             }
             throw new Exception("Unknown material quality " + quality);
        }

    }
}
```

and later you can use that:

```
    //....
    Material materialData = Material.GetFor(quality);
    Cost = materialData.Cost;
    Value = materialData.Value;
    //...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's not quite what I'm after, I want to keep the configuration of `MaterialQuality` separate in for ex. Config.cs for non-technicals to edit without going into the main `Material` class

Answer (score 1):

I would use a struct and static properties in MaterialQuantity instead of an enum. Something like the following:

```
public struct MaterialQualityInfo
{
    public MaterialQualityInfo( float value, int cost )
    {
        Value = value;
        Cost = cost;
    }

    public float Value { get; private set; }
    public int Cost { get; private set; }
}

public static class Config
{
    public static class MaterialQuality
    {
        public static MaterialQualityInfo Low
        {
            get { return new MaterialQualityInfo( 0.1f, 10 ); }
        }

        public static MaterialQualityInfo Medium
        {
            get { return new MaterialQualityInfo( 0.2f, 20 ); }
        }

        public static MaterialQualityInfo High
        {
            get { return new MaterialQualityInfo( 0.2f, 40 ); }
        }
    }
}

public class Material
{
    private int Cost;
    private float Value;

    Material( MaterialQualityInfo quality )
    {

        Cost = quality.Cost;
        Value = quality.Value;

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I like this approach, it keeps configuration separate to the main logic of `Material` but it removes the `enum` requirement which in most circumstances is a good thing, but I actually need to provide non-technical people with a simple configuration selection, a `enum` in unity3d is the simplest way to offer this, as it provides a designer with a simple dropdown selection.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, this isn't a good usage of static classes. You should use regular object-oriented programming to solve the issue.

I see that all material qualities have 2 properties in common: `Value` and `Cost`. For me, this means that you should design a class called `MaterialQuality`:

```
public class MaterialQuality
{
     public float Value { get; set; }
     public int Cost { get; set; }
}
```

If *material qualities* are part of an application configuration, I see that you should design a `Configuration` class as follows:

```
public class Configuration
{
    public List<MaterialQuality> MaterialQualities { get; } = new List<MaterialQuality>();
}
```

...and if you want to initialize a configuration per application life-cycle, you can improve `Configuration` class using *static field initializers*:

```
public class Configuration
{
    private readonly static Configuration _current = new Configuration();

    public static Configuration Current => _current;

    public List<MaterialQuality> MaterialQualities { get; } = new List<MaterialQuality>();
}
```

Now adding new material qualities to current configuration is as easy as the following code:

```
Configuration.Current.MaterialQualities.Add(new MaterialQualities { Value = 0.1f, Cost = 10 });
```

If you want to provide a fluent API to add material qualities is also easy: we're going to turn public `MaterialQualities` properties into an `ImmutableList<T>` (*so you force developers to add materials using the method to do so*) and add an `AddMaterial` method:

```
public class Configuration
{
    private readonly static Configuration _current = new Configuration();
    private readonly List<MaterialQuality> _materialQualities = new List<MaterialQuality>();

    public static Configuration Current => _current;

    public IImmutableList<MaterialQuality> MaterialQualities => _materialQualities.ToImmutableList();

    public Configuration AddMaterial(float value, int cost)
    {
         _materialQualities.Add(new MaterialQuality { Value = value, Cost = cost });

         return this;
    }
}
```

...and now adding many materials would look even nicer!

```
Configuration.Current.AddMaterial(0.1f, 10)
                     .AddMaterial(0.2f, 20)
                     .AddMaterial(0.2f, 40);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer looks clean. you must have skipped over the second block of code. `public enum MaterialQuantity`

Comment: @Rob Oh, yeah, I missed it. I'm going to edit the answer ;)

Comment: This looks like a good approach in a typical situation, however I'm actually using c# in a unity3d project, for which an `enum` provides a simple mechanic for a dev to allow a level designer to select a property of an object.

Comment: Yes, my apologies I should have tagged it earlier, however I did specify that I wanted to access the configuration using an `enum` value in the origin question.

Comment: @Rob Sometimes a tag might change the meaning of  the question. While adding or removing tags is open forever, if you want to get good answers, you need to be as specific as possible ;)

Comment: @Rob But you said this in your question: **Whether or not this is the right approach here I'm not 100% at the moment. Would be greatful of other suggested approaches.**. Now, please, don't edit your question and drop this sentence too haha

Comment: Agreed, I guess everything is open to interpretation & I've already accepted my tagging error. I have received plenty of very good answers including yours for which I am grateful. I'm not going to get into an extended discussion about the semantics as this is neither the time nor the place. Thanks for your contribution and have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
public enum MaterialQuality
{
    Low, Medium, High
}

public class Material
{
    private int Cost;
    private float Value;
    private readonly Dictionary<MaterialQuality, Tuple<int, float>> storageMap = new Dictionary<MaterialQuality, Tuple<int, float>>
    {
        { MaterialQuality.Low, Tuple.Create(10, 0.1f)},
        { MaterialQuality.Low, Tuple.Create(20, 0.2f)},
        { MaterialQuality.Low, Tuple.Create(40, 0.2f)},
    }; 

    public Material(MaterialQuality quality)
    {

        Cost = storageMap[quality].Item1;
        Value = storageMap[quality].Item2;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's not quite what I'm after, I want to keep the configuration of `MaterialQuality` separate in for ex. Config.cs for non-technicals to edit without going into the main `Material` class

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using your enum widely, you could do something like:

```
public class Material
{
   public float Value { get; private set; }
   public int Cost { get; private set; }
   public Material(float value, int cost)
   {
     Value = value;
     Cost = cost;
   }
   public static Material Low { get { return new Material(0.1f, 10); } }
   public static Material Medium { get { return new Material(0.2f, 20); } }
   public static Material High { get { return new Material(0.2f, 40); } }
}
```

And then:

```
var myLowMaterial = Material.Low;
var myMediumMaterial = Material.Medium;
var myHighMaterial = Material.High;
```

Unless you are using your `enum` for something, in which case you could add:

```
 public static Material Get(MaterialQuality quality)
 {
   switch(quality)
   {
     case MaterialQuality.Low: 
        return Low;
     case MaterialQuality.Medium: 
        return Medium;
     case MaterialQuality.High: 
        return High;
   }
   throw new Exception("We should never go here");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is not quite what I'm after, I want to keep the configuration separate from the application logic & retain use of `enum` to allow ease of configuration for non technical level designers.